# Please give a hint for the following NBHM problem

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Please give some hint regarding the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x\in S^{1}$, let us define the map $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$. Note that $g(-x)=-g(x)$. Now if there exists some point $x_0\in S^{1}$ such that $g(x_0)=0$, we are done, that is we have $f(x_0)=f(-x_0)$. Suppose $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in S^{1}$. In view of $g(-x)=-g(x)$, we can say that $g$ assumes both positive and negative values in $\mathbb{R}$. Observe that range of $g$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $g$ assumes both positive and negative values, hence zero must belong to the range of $g$. In particular there exists some point $p\in S^{1}$ such that $g(p)=0\implies f(p)=f(-p)$. Hence $A$ is non-empty.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g\colon S^1\to\Bbb  R$, $x\mapsto f(x)-f(-x)$. Then $g$ is continuous and $g(-x)=-g(x)$. Can you show that $g(x)=0$ for some $x$?